# Should i install Kali linux OS as a virtual in a vitual machine, use a live USB stick or should I Dual boot my PC

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently, I have started performing **penetration test** lessons. My PC(HP PROBOOK) has a pre-installed windows 10 enterprise. A friend advised me to use Kali Linux. However, I need to run both OS in my PC but I don't know which option to use. When I use the Dual boot option, I will not have access to the wireless network similar to the virtual machine (*am using VIRTUALBOX*). Opting for the live USB stick scares me off since my work won't be saved...I don't know so much about this too. I need to have full compatibility of KALI LINUX as if it was being used as the MAIN OS.
Which is the best option to use, and if any other option let me know.

I used this to find some risks https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/risks-dual-booting-windows-linux-operating-systems/

Comment: Either VirtualBox or LiveUSB with Persistence. Don't dual-boot. There are a number of questions (and answers) here explaining about using pass-through so that Kali can see the WiFi adapter - but be aware that you can't use the same adapter for your network and for monitoring at the same time so you may need to buy a second

Answer (score 3):

It depends quite a bit on what you want.

- if you are just testing and want to get to know Kali, use a virtual machine.
- if you really want to do wifi tests and/or network tests, but not on a regular basis, use a live image with persistence.
- If you know Linux and Windows fairly good, have experience with the USB and networks of virtual box and are not afraid to tweak a bit, you may use a VirtualBox image.
- If you need to have Kali available for a long time you may consider dual boot, but a live image gives you practically the same.
- If you are really want to get into pentesting and/or forensics, buy a separate laptop (cheap secondhand or something like that). (This is what I did.)

The main advantage of running VirtualBox Kali is of course that you still have your host available (in your case: the windows machine) when Kali is running, where as you use a live image, you don't.

Comment: +1 for interpreting this question in a more practical less opinion based way.

Comment: I think I will go for a live image before I get myself a new laptop.